# RequiredValidation only active when another control contain a value

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two dropdownlists, if one of them contain a value (not default value, which is empty string), the other should also have a value (like requredvalidator). But if no one has a value the page should validate 'true'.
I cannot solve it with a validation group, because the button that trigger the validation is already triggering other validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use a custom validator control and put your logic in the server side validation method. Keep it in the same validation group.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valCust" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="ddlControl" ErrorMessage="error Message" 
                ValidationGroup="Group" 
                onservervalidate="valCust_ServerValidate" >*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

code behind

```
 protected void valCust_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     args.IsValid = MethodToWorkOutValidation();

}
```

Comment: Erm client side validation on custom validator - http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t112691-how-do-i-use-client-side-validation-with-a-custom-validator.html. Sorry to be obvious

Comment: yeah... thought about that... so I'm sorry about not being clearer in my text. If there are no standard controls that could do this, I have to create it in a custom validator.

Comment: You can add the `ClientValidationFunction` property of the `CustomValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

please check below code snippet.

```
 function EnableDisableValidator() {
        var DropDownList1 = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
        var DropDownList2 = document.getElementById('DropDownList2');
        var RequiredFieldValidator12 = document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator12');
        if (DropDownList1.selectedIndex > 0 && DropDownList2.selectedIndex > 0) {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator12'), true);

        }
        else {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator12'), false);
        }
    }
```

..........

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="EnableDisableValidator();">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" onchange="EnableDisableValidator();">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="*************" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Let me know if any concern